# Bash Loop and exit status check

Tags: bash, loops, exit-code

An array holds the files accessed, and the archive files are split into smaller sizes in preparation for online backup. I am attempting to retrieve the exit code for each iteration through the loop of the split command. However, it is returning `Exit Code 1`, yet it says that the operation was successful. Why?

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a SplitDirs
declare -a CFiles
CDIR=/mnt/Net_Pics/Working/Compressed/
SDIR=/mnt/Net_Pics/Working/Split/
Err=/mnt/Net_Pics/Working
SplitDirs=(`ls -l "$CDIR" --time-style="long-iso" | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $8}'`)
for dir in "${SplitDirs[@]}"
do
  if [ ! -d "$SDIR""$dir" ]; then
mkdir "$SDIR""$dir"
  else continue
  fi
CFiles=(`ls -l "$CDIR$dir" --time-style="long-iso" | awk '{print $8}'`)
  for f in "${CFiles[@]}"
  do
  if [ ! -e "$SDIR""$dir"/"$f" ]; then 
    split -d -a 4 -b 1992295 "$CDIR""$dir"/"$f" "$SDIR""$dir"/"$f" --verbose
    if [[ "$?" == 1 ]]
    then
      rm -rf "$SDIR""$dir" && echo "$SDIR""$dir" "Removed due to Error code" "$?""." "Testing Archives and Retrying..." 2>&1 | tee "$Err"/Split_Err.log
      7z t "$CDIR""$dir"/"$f" >> tee stdout.log 2>> "$Err"/"$dir"/7z_Err.log >&2
      mkdir "$SDIR""$dir" && split -d -a 4 -b 1992295 "$CDIR""$dir"/"$f" "$SDIR""$dir"/"$f" --verbose
       if [[ "$?" == 1 ]]
       then
          rm -rf "$SDIR""$dir" && echo "$SDIR""$dir" "Removed a second time due to Error code "$?". Skipping..." 2>&1 | tee "$Err"/Split_Err.log
          continue
       else
          echo "Split Success:" "$SDIR""$dir"/"$f" "ended with Exit status" "$?" && continue
       fi
    else
      echo "Split Success:" "$SDIR""$dir" "ended with Exit status" "$?" && continue
    fi 
  else
    echo "$SDIR""$dir"/"$f" "Exists... Skipping Operation" 2>&1 | tee "$Err"/"$dir"/Split_Err.log
    continue
  fi
  done
```

(The echo piping in a previous revision of the question was misplaced code, and thank you for pointing that out. The exit code remains the same, though. Overall,the script does what I want it to except for the exit code portion.)

Comment: That's some serious coding style inconsistency.  There are quite a few things wrong with this script that could cause it to break, like the fact that you're piping through your `echo $?`, you aren't quoting your variables, you're redirecting (instead of piping) through `tee`...  Perhaps you could try cleaning up the script first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `| echo $?`. you are processing the return code of `echo` command(last command).